# how to get the output of a background running script in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i am calling a script through java using Runtime.getRuntime().exec()  and let the script run in background to create a file, how to get the output in servlet whenever the file is completed even if working on other pages

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get the output of the execution of command but you cannot get the output of background process which takes more time. For more time consuming command you have to schedule the command using javascript you can poll for the command output periodically.

```
public void executeAndGetResponse( HttpServletResponse response ) {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "some command" );

    if( process != null ) {
        int status = process.getWaitFor(); // wait for completion
        InputStream in = null;
        if( status == 0 ) {         
            in = process.getInputStream(); // if success get output
        } else {
            in = process.getErrorStream(); // if failure get error
        }
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(in,out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But i want to download the file using ftp whenever the file creation task is completed, for that i want to read the output of the script running in background.